# how we display the barcodes in our design

Tags: android

[image]Hi i want to display the barcodes in my application.Is there any predefined view for this one .How i want means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/). Many graphing solutions for Android are presented.